# ng serve issue Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema' on mac

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, jsonschema, serve

On my windows machine i can run ng serve but when i try it on mac i get this error:

```
module.js:544
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ngtools/json-schema'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:6:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
```

i tried to npm install json-schema but it doesn't help. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing node and npm and install it again.
 Use the following versions:

- **Node 8.0.0**
- **npm 5.0.0:** `$ npm install npm@5.0.0`
- **angular-cli 1.0.0:**  `$ npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0`